# Merge two rasters with no data value

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, grass-gis, nodata

I have two rasters: Raster A and B. Raster A has has only values of 0. The white area in Raster B are No Data values. I want to merge them to one raster (Raster C). So basically I want all pixels in Raster B with a No Data value to have a value of 0.

I tried to do this with the raster calculator in QGIS by adding Raster A to Raster B, but it only returns again Raster B.

I am looking for solutions with QGIS, GDAL, or Grass GIS.

[image]

Comment: You would benefit by reviewing the [GRASS map calculator expressions](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.mapcalc.html) that are available, paying special attention to how they support null data.  They provide many solutions, such as combining `isnull` with the conditional operator `?:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a GDAL python script, that replaces the NoDataValue with a new value (in my case 0):

```
import gdal, ogr, osr, os
import numpy as np

def raster2array(rasterfn):
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    return band.ReadAsArray()

def getNoDataValue(rasterfn):
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    return band.GetNoDataValue()

def array2raster(rasterfn,newRasterfn,array):
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    geotransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
    originX = geotransform[0]
    originY = geotransform[3] 
    pixelWidth = geotransform[1] 
    pixelHeight = geotransform[5]
    cols = raster.RasterXSize
    rows = raster.RasterYSize

    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
    outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
    outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
    outband.WriteArray(array)
    outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    outRasterSRS.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
    outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
    outband.FlushCache()


rasterfn = 'Slope.tif'
newValue = 0
newRasterfn = 'SlopeNew.tif'

# Convert Raster to array
rasterArray = raster2array(rasterfn)

# Get no data value of array
noDataValue = getNoDataValue(rasterfn)

# Updata no data value in array with new value
rasterArray[rasterArray == noDataValue] = newValue

# Write updated array to new raster
array2raster(rasterfn,newRasterfn,rasterArray)
```

Answer (score 4):

One solution may be this batch script:

```
set nodatavalue=-99999
gdalwarp -srcnodata None rasterB_with_NoData.tif rasterB_without_NoData.tif
python gdal_calc.py -A rasterB_without_NoData.tif --outfile=rasterB_updated_with_NoData.tif --calc="(A<>%nodatavalue%)*A"
gdalwarp -srcnodata None rasterB_updated_with_NoData.tif rasterB_updated_without_NoData.tif
```

The trick is **`-srcnodata None`** offered by `gdalwarp`, which is very useful in order *to ignore intrinsic nodata settings on the source dataset* (from the [doc](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html)). In detail, we need to apply it two times: firstly because we need to substitute the NoData value with 0 and so we have to include it in the calculation, secondly because `gdal_calc.py` introduces NoData value again.